# Excel 2007 custom formatting; text placeholder (@) returns address instead of value

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007. I want to have certain text formatted to have it surrounded by square brackets by using the Format Cells option. I use custom type `\[@\]`. Whenever I enter a value in the cell with this formatting it displays the formatting correct:

`Optimus Prime` becomes `[Optimus Prime]` etc.

But when I put in a reference to another cell, it returns displays the reference to this cell:

Cell A1 contains `Ford Prefect`
Cell A2 contains the reference to A1 and formatting as stated above. This results in displaying: `[=A1]`

Is it possible to display the references as value with the above method?

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the Excel nice little things (it has many).

You have to apply the formatting after you enter the formula.
Reset cell formatting to General.
Enter the formula.
Apply the `\[@\]` format.

Comment: Yes, that works. Nice find! Unfortunately that is not convenient in my situation, I want it to work the other way around.

Comment: Well, you can handle the [`Worksheet_Change`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080555120.aspx) event and remove-set-reapply from there. Other than that, I can't really see a way.

Comment: That could be a workaround. I think I will create a shortcut to remove-set-reapply, like how ctrl+alt+F5 works to manually recalculate/refresh the workbook.